# Obtener elemento html de una solicitud AJAX con JSONP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsonp

Estoy haciendo una solicitud con ajax y javascript, la respuesta de dicha solicitud es una pagina html completa, de esta respuesta necesito obtener el valor de un elemento `<input type="hidden" name="key_solicitud" value="este es el valor que deseo obtener">`, he intentado con el siguiente codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="html_response"></p>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax(
        {
            type : 'GET',
            crossDomain:true,
            url: 'http://cartago.lllf.uam.es/grampal/grampal.cgi?m=etiqueta',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            callback: function(result) {
                var mydata = $(result).filter('key_solicitud').value();
                $('#html_response').html(mydata);
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y varias variantes como find por filter(), $(result).filter('key_solicitud').text(); pero siempre tengo un error al obtener el resultado

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

[image: vista de herramientas de desarrollo]

[image: resultado de url en Restlet Client]

Comment: El contenido de tu url lo tienes?

Comment: Hola Ricardo, te refieres a lo que devuelve la url?

Comment: Si, así es, por que el método .html(), recibe un htmlString, quiere decir que el contenido que te retorna tu ajax, debe de ser una cadena, y tal vez por eso te esta dando error.

Comment: El contenido que retorna es un html de una pagina completa, subire una imagen de este contenido en Restlet Client

Comment: El error que te da es por que estas mandando elementos html, y la funcion .html(), recibe un htmlString, osea que necesitas convertir tu html en una cadena para que la funcion lo pueda interpretar.

Comment: var str = $result.prop('outerHTML'); esto es correcto? porque previamente lo provee y nogenera resultado

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas primero tomar tu pagina como texto, para después parsearlo y convertirlo a `html`, una vez convertido, tenemos que recorrer todos los elementos creados y encontrar el que tenga el `name` correspondiente al que buscas, y de ese objeto tomar el `value`.

Creo que hay maneras mas optimas de hacerlo, esto solo es un ejemplo que puede mejorar.

Este es el ejemplo:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento 1</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="html_response"></p>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax(
            {
                type : 'GET',
                crossDomain:true,
                url: 'http://cartago.lllf.uam.es/grampal/grampal.cgi?m=etiqueta',
                dataType: 'html',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                success: function(result) {
                    var mydata = $.parseHTML(result);
                    for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++){
                       if (mydata[i].name == "key_solicitud") {
                          $('#html_response').html(mydata[i].value);
                       }
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero al cambiar el dataType a html se genera un error de autenticacion.** Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://cartago.lllf.uam.es/grampal/grampal.cgi?m=etiqueta' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: Utiliza [esta extension de chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) con eso te debe funcionar.